# tranfer data to azure sql database using azure datalake analytics

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

is it possible to load data in an azure SQL database using azure data lake analytics. if so please tell me the OUT PUTTERS that is used

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to do this directly with Azure SQL Database and Azure Data Lake Analytics (ADLA).  ADLA normally outputs either to Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS) or blob storage (or an ADLA database).  It would be possible to use Azure Data Factory to move data from ADLS to Azure SQL Database.  Example workflow:

> Data Factory orchestrates movement of data from ADLS to Azure SQL
>   Database

This would be also possible with Azure SQL Data Warehouse (ADW) which has Polybase integration with ADLS.  Example workflow:

> U-SQL script outputs flat file to ADLS > Polybase / External table in
>   ADW schematizes flat file